Error with Electron-Vite in production: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
Note: This does not occur in the development (npm run dev) environment. The development version will refresh as intended without the error.
I have an Electron-Vite app in deployment that uses a cronjob to fetch data from the server every morning and refresh the frontend. Every morning the production version returns the same error when the cronjob is supposed to execute:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Despite having retry logic, nothing gets fetched and the page data remains stale until a user manually hits the refresh button, at which point everything refreshes as intended.


export const fetchWithRetry = async (url, options = {}, maxRetries = 3, delay = 5000) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < maxRetries; i++) {
    try {
      const response = await axios(url, options);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Attempt ${i + 1} failed:`, error.message);

      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Response data:", error.response.data);
        console.error("Response status:", error.response.status);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.error("No response received:", error.request);
      } else {
        console.error("Error setting up request:", error.message);
      }

      if (i === maxRetries - 1) {
        throw error; // Rethrow the error after all retries have failed
      }

      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    }
  }
};



Here are my electron window settings:


  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1600,
    height: 800,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: false,
    ...(process.platform === "linux" ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, "../preload/index.js"),
      sandbox: false,
      webSecurity: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });



